# как изменить стили у одного элемента ::before

Tags: html, css

я понимаю, что style="" использовать неприлично, но всё-же не понимаю, как задавать стили псевдоэлементу ::before этого элемента?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  padding-left:34px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  line-height:2
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:-30px;
    top:-1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>здесь эмоджи</li>
  <li>тут тоже эмоджи</li>
  <li style="">какие стили задать в style=""?, если эмоджи не нужен именно тут тут</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  padding-left:34px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  line-height:2
}

li:nth-child(3)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:-30px;
    top:-1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>здесь эмоджи</li>
  <li>тут тоже эмоджи</li>
  <li style="">какие стили задать в style=""?, если эмоджи не нужен именно тут тут</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: нет, я говорю про тег style="" в HTML

Comment: `stile`- не тег, а атрибут... Во-вторых нет такой возможности...

Comment: @ben, можно создать ТЕГ `<style></style>` и впиндюрить его в верстку, если прям уж очень сильно хочется